# Symmetric spectrum associated to a ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510247.pdf) by Dwyer, Greenlees and Iyengar, we are introduced to symmetric spectra, and more particularly to the notion of an $\mathbb{S}$-algebra.

In both the *Notation and terminology* ($1.5$), and *Rings and DGAs vs. $\mathbb{S}$-algebras* ($2.17$) sections, it is said that we can convert any ring $R$ into an $\mathbb{S}$-algebra.

The procedure for turning a (unbounded) chain complex into an $\mathbb{S}$-algebra is touched on in Section $2.6$, but not the case of a ring.

How do we go from a ring $R$ to an $\mathbb{S}$-algebra? Specifically, do we assume that a ring is a DGA concentrated in degree zero?

EDIT: Another candidate, as suggested in the comments by William, is to let $HR$ be the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum for the underlying abelian group of $R$.

Comment: I'm not sure which specific definition of $\mathbb{S}$-algebra they're using, but does the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum $HR$ work?

Comment: In this case $R$ is a ring rather than an abelian group, so I am not sure what the definition of Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum here should be (short of the one where we simply forget the ring multiplicattion of $R$ and take the underlying abelian group). I don't have much of a feel for this so I don't know, though.

Comment: For a commutative ring $R$ there are ways to construct $HR$ so that it is naturally a ring-spectrum, see for example the [nLab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Mac+Lane+spectrum#AsSymmetricSpectra) (It should be in Adams' "Stable Homotopy and Generalised Homology" but I don't have a copy available to check)